# guardar datos en un archivo txt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, archivo

estoy queriendo guardar una cadena de texto en un archivo txt.
Lo que tengo es que si me guarda la cadena pero la primera vez y las demas cadenas que le mando ya no me las guarda.

```
public void regText(string cadena)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"reg.txt")))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",cadena));
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

lo que quiero es que la segunda vez que llamo a mi metodo, deberia de grabar abajo de la primera linea y asi sucesivamente, cada vez que lo llamo siempre le paso texto en el parametro **cadena** de mi metodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade `append: true` a `new StreamWriter()`:

```cs
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"reg.txt"), append: true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",cadena));
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola ¿has intentado usar `WriteAsync`?

```
  using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, "WriteTextAsync.txt")))
        {
            await outputFile.WriteAsync("This is a sentence.");
        }
```

Aquí te dejo la referencia

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file